# Asking for how to reduce the time for the multiple fittings

Tags: python, performance, matlab, vectorization, curve-fitting

**Dear all in this community:**

Hello. I am trying to do **curve fitting at each voxel** (e.g., in 2D image, it would be a pixel) through "**Matlab**". Thus, simply, I hope to do **"curve fittings a huge number of times"** (e.g., 256X256X500 times), but as expected,  it requires a lot of time (roughly a year) under the assumption that the time for a single fitting would take roughly 1 sec.

**Except for CUDA programming**, **is there some way to solve the issue in the Matlab?** I am currently using Matlab and my code is executed with **"triple for-loops"** and "**lsqcurvefit** (i.e., built-in function for fitting)". **Could I get some help to reduce the calculation time?** (e.g., **how to make the fitting process vectorized?**)

Any comments would be really helpful to me. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, you what is the calculation I mean you take one voxel (lets say X(1,1,1) or X(1,1,:) ?) and what else are you using?

Comment: Hello Ulises. Thanks you for your reply. You can assume that, in a voxel, there are two sets of measured data (i.e., time points & measured values).; because, i already made Cell Array volume through Matlab. Thus, in a single cell, i can save arrays rather than a single number. Ultimately,  i hope to use the measured data sets for a single curve fitting. But, problem is that i also hope to repeat the fitting at each voxel(i.e. each cell) in a volume, which is comprised of e.g. 256X256X500.

Comment: first of all avoid the usage of cells if you can, because that could slow your program. Beside that you maybe can reshape your data or use (:) to avoid some fors

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Do we have some way to do curve fitting simultaneously at each voxel by modifying the "lsqcurvefit" function?

Comment: I still haven't a clear idea of your problem, but maybe fit your models other ways, what kind of curve are you fitting?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. To clarify my issue further, i hope to do fitting a huge number of times, of course based on the same curve function (e.g., linear curve) Actually, the curve function that i really want to be fitted to the measured data is not linear curve, but, let's assume that it is the linear curve to make the issue simple. I just hope to know regarding how to reduce the whole fitting time when we have to do a huge number of fittings, except for using gpu or cpu parallel processing.